# WiFi new networks don't work until I reboot my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless

When I try to connect to a new wifi network, it doesn't work. All what I do is to reboot my PC then it works perfectly.

please tell me how to debug this problem and get it solved.

Comment: Start by looking at the logs, with the command: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: Have you tried just disabling and re-enabling the network adapter?